# how to pass one function values to another in - angular 2 service

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, pass-by-reference, subscription

Need help, to **pass the data to one function to another in angular 2 application**.

In this application i am getting the data from server

**Issue :** Unable to send the data to one function to another function in service.ts

**Expected:** Get the values and read it in second function.

**Please note:** Since it is a server client integration i dont have a plunker or jsfiddle.

**First function**

```
  getDLFolders() {

    return this.http.get(this.url + '/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser/root/sites/' + this.targetSite + '/documentLibrary/' + this.targetFolder + '?/cmisselector=children&succinct=true&alf_ticket=' + this.ticket)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        resGetRecords => {

          //get objects from document folders
          let objectGroup = resGetRecords.objects;
          let objectIDs = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < objectGroup.length; i++) {

            //push object ID's from folder
            objectIDs.push(objectGroup[i].object.succinctProperties["cmis:objectId"]);
          }
          return objectIDs;
          //this will return []array with following values
          //5645cf45-9b6c-4ad2-ad18-91d24c31f837;1.0
         //4712dc17-0c9f-439f-8577-0c80e52d7afc;1.0
        }
      );
  }
```

**Second function**

```
  getJson() {
   //how to get the getDLFolders function return values
    for (var i = 0; i < objectIDs.length; i++) {
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser/root?objectId='+ objectIDs[i] +'&alf_ticket=' + this.ticket)
      .map(res => res.json());
    }
  }
```

**Subscribing in another file**

```
export class UserdashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  details = [];
  records = [];
  errorMsg: string;

  constructor(private _myRecords: AuthService, private _myDocuments: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //get user details, 
    this._myRecords.getPeople()
      .subscribe(
      resGetRecords => {
        // first name, last name
        this.details = resGetRecords;
      },
      resRecordsError => this.errorMsg = resRecordsError
      );

    //get document Libary records of user , 
    this._myDocuments.getJson()
      .subscribe(
      resGetRecords => {
        //debugger;
        // folders
        this.records = resGetRecords;
        console.log(this.records);

      },
      resRecordsError => this.errorMsg = resRecordsError
      );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misused the `subscribe` method. It doesn't `return` a value since it's `asynchronous` but instead a `Subscription` object here's an example on usage:

```
// this returns the Observable<Response> object
httpGet() {
  return this.http.get('url');
}

// lets just print it out for now with 2nd function
secondFunction(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

// code inside 'subscribe' will execute at a later time when you receive 
// the response from the server hence it won't return the value like a normal function
this.httpGet().subscribe(
  (response: Response) => {
    console.log(response); // this will still work
    return response; // this won't work
  }
);

// if you wish to use the response data you need to call the 2nd function from
// within the 'subscribe' method
this.httpGet().subscribe(
  (response: Response) => {
    secondFunction(response); // send data to 2nd function and print it there
  }
);
```

Edit:

As promised I've written some more examples on how to handle `async` operations in Angular 2/4.

Here's a [plunkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/w9RcEauCbRdJpsQXhsaL):

- first example is simple `Say hello` where you `subscribe` in the constructor and emit the value on button click
- in second example we create a new emitter because plunkr didn't let me import `Observable` properly and I didn't have much time to write this, then we subscribe and listen for the fake response from the server, when it arrives we handle it by first parsing it from `JSON` and then alerting it's properties and values

Second example is how you should handle server response in your service, there're a lot of existing examples like the ones on official angular page:

[Tour of Heroes Angular Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial)

Do note that this is how every `AJAX` request should be handled in Angular.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
i did take lot of time understand this, answer looks very clear but when i am implementing with my code, it was not clear. Finally i end up with using local storage.

Comment: I can make you a fiddle later today, if you work with Angular you absolutely need to learn how to work with `Observables`.